# Boolean Values Not Saved, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

I have some `boolean` fields sent with a `POST` request to a Laravel controller. However, every data in the request is saved except the `booleans`.

**Model Fillables**:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'code',
        'governorate',
        'point',
        'overnight',
        'isResort',
        'family',
        'youth',
        'status',
        'description',
        'user_id',
        'price_currency',
        'map',
        'checkoutMessage',
        'checkoutYoutubeVideo',
        'max_person_count',
        'more_person_price',
        'age_limit',
        'productYoutubeVideo',
        'resortProductCount',
    ];
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            
            $data = $request->all();
            $data['user_id'] = auth('user-api')->user()->id;
            
            $gev_id = Str::before($request->governorate_id, ',');
            
            $product = RentProduct::create($data);
            
            $product->update([
                'code' => $gev_id.rand((int)0, (int)pow(2, 256)).$product->id,
            ]);


            return $this->returnData("product", RentProduct::where('id', $product->id)->with('photos')->get());

        }catch(\Throwable $th){

            return $this->returnError($th->getCode() , $th->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The strange problem is when I die & dump the created product from the `store` method, `boolean` appears in the proper nature but it is saved without that `boolean`s.

Postman request
[image: Postman Request]

Comment: Are they really boolean or strings?

Comment: Show the migration for your `rent_products` table (or whatever your the name is); did you define those boolean columns as `$table->boolean()` (or `$table->tinyInteger()`). Also, you won't see `true` or `false` in the database; booleans are saved a `0` and `1` (binary).

Comment: is your postman request a JSON post request?

Comment: I don't see any attempt in the code to handle boolean values. The string "true" is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send 'true' as a string, send 1 (true) or 0 (false) as a int. By the way don't forget to change your column type to tinyint(1) data type.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this and strangely `$product->my_boolean_value = "true"` did not work but `$product->setAttribute("my_boolean_value", "false")` worked when the database-column is defined as boolean on PostgreSQL. My Model is defined as:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'my_boolean_value' => 'boolean'
    ];
}
```